# Consuming ArcGIS Server map service (MapServer) from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, map-service

I have a map service at https://geoportal.esdm.go.id/monaresia/rest/services/4.GEOLOGI/Kebencanaan_Geologi/MapServer/ (I know the framework is disabled, but we can see the layers using https://geoportal.esdm.go.id/monaresia/rest/services/4.GEOLOGI/Kebencanaan_Geologi/MapServer?f=pjson).

When I add it to QGIS (`Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS Map Server Layer`) it displayed perfectly (although I had to ignore some security certification) I have no problem. However, when I used ArcGIS Pro to add the same server (`Insert -> Connections -> add WMS layer`), it prompted for authentication.

I don't understand how the same map server is able to be displayed by QGIS without authentication but require authentication if I use ArcGIS Pro.

How do I add the map service to ArcGIS Pro without authentication?

Comment: You are doing another thing with QGIS. Try Layer -> Add Layer -> Add WMS/WMTS Layer. Does that also work with QGIS without authentication?

Comment: @user30184 No, I can't but that's not the problem. What I want is to display the MapServer in ArcGIS. I can display the MapServer with QGIS, but I don't know how to do the same thing with ArcGIS.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add an ArcGIS Map Service layer in ArcGIS, NOT a WMS layer.  They are quite different things.

Comment: @SonofaBeach exactly. That's why I'm confused, in QGIS there is an "Add ArcGIS Map Server" option; what's the equivalent in ArcGIS? How do I display the mapserver in ArcGIS without authentification?

Comment: Click the little dropdown v that's part of the Add Data button in the Map tab, then click Data From Path and paste in the URL https://geoportal.esdm.go.id/monaresia/rest/services/4.GEOLOGI/Kebencanaan_Geologi/MapServer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1 I followed the [instructions of @user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374433/connect-wms-is-able-with-qgis-but-not-with-arcgis-how-to-connect-to-wms-with-ar/374440#comment611727_374433):

> Click the little dropdown v that's part of the Add Data button in the
> Map tab, then click Data From Path and paste in the URL
> https://geoportal.esdm.go.id/monaresia/rest/services/4.GEOLOGI/Kebencanaan_Geologi/MapServer/

and the ArcGIS Server Map Service at that URL displayed in an ArcGIS Pro Map view without any authentication being requested:

[image]

Even though "MapServer" appears in your URL path name the map service you are making the request of is served by ArcGIS Server and not the open source MapServer product.